# WP8 Application closes with out error, While navigating between pages

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows phone 8 application. Everything is working fine, but while i am navigating from one screen to other (using NavigationService.Navigate) , the app closes intermittently. There are no errors/exceptions but app closes and takes me to the apps list. This is happening 1-2 times if i navigation around 10 times.

Anyone else also facing same issue?, please share the solution for the same.

Comment: can you show us your code

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); this is what i use to navigate from one page to another.. while this code is executing the app closes (sometimes) with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

So it's easy, use relative, because it's relative to the current directory.

Change

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

to

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: but the same code works most of the time and fails on few occasions.. like first 6-7 attempts it works after that every 5 attempts it fails 2-3 times

Comment: do u pass any parameter between pages

Comment: See Sharp, The above change did not help.

Comment: can u send me a simple or something

Answer (score 0):

If you're navigating between the same pages, you should use the first opened page as the start point and then use backward navigation to return to that page:

`NavigationService.GoBack();`

This removes the current page from the `BackStack` and restores the previous one. Otherwise use the normal navigation:

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyNewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

You should try that and if it doesn't help, debug the page initialization and loads line by line.